# How to make controls of a customized javascript carousel

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a customized javascript carousel . I would like to make controls for my carousel . I was searching for the answer but didn't find .

here is the code which I was working with

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 top-space text-center float">
      <h3 class="heading">Image Slider</h3>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 float">
      <img src="img/slider1.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="mainImage">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
 var imagesArray = ["img/slider2.jpg","img/slider3.jpg","img/slider4.jpg"];
 var index = 0 ;

 function imageSlider(){

   var getImagePath = document.getElementById("mainImage");
   getImagePath.setAttribute("src",imagesArray[index]);
   index++;

   if(index >= imagesArray.length){
     index = 0;
   }
}

setInterval(imageSlider,4000);
```

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: Add elements and wire up their click events to the imageSlider function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a example for you:**

```js
function imageSlider(){
  this.prev = function(){
    if(--this.index < 0) this.index = this.imagesArray.length - 1;
    this.start()
  };

  this.next = function(){
    if(++this.index >= this.imagesArray.length) this.index = 0;
    this.start()
  };

  this.start = function(){
    var getImagePath = document.getElementById("mainImage");
    getImagePath.setAttribute("src", this.imagesArray[this.index]);

    this.timeout && clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(this.next.bind(this),3000) 
  };
}

var myCarousel = new imageSlider();
myCarousel.imagesArray = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5vO7.jpg?s=128&g=1", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNgxX.png?s=128&g=1","https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpQYd.png?s=128&g=1"];
myCarousel.index = 0;
myCarousel.start()
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 float">
      <img src="img/slider1.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="mainImage">
      <p><button onclick="myCarousel.prev()">Prev</button>
      <button onclick="myCarousel.next()">Next</button></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all index should be increased before assigning the new path. After that, simply create a button that calls the imageSlider() function you have created and the slider should go an image forward. If you wan't to make it go backwards you'll have to create another function to do that. Something like:

```
   var getImagePath = document.getElementById("mainImage");
   index--;
   getImagePath.setAttribute("src",imagesArray[index]);


   if(index <= 0){
     index =  imagesArray.length - 1;
   }
```

To implement the button functionality you can use the jQuery .click() method: https://api.jquery.com/click/

or use the Javascript only alternative: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp