# the second dot does not become active when the image changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a little automatic slider that changes image every 4 seconds so I call my function with

`setInterval(displayImage, 4000);`.

The images are changed perfectly; when the first image is shown the first dot present (represented by ol) remains active , while the second remains disabled and so far so good.

When the image changes, i.e. the second is shown, both remain disabled (while I want the first to be disabled and the second dot active).

Where am I doing wrong? This is my code:

```js
function displayImage() {
    let nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".sliderimg");
    let pointer = document.querySelectorAll("ol.controlnav li a")
    for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < pointer.length; j++) {
            if (nodeList[i].classList.contains("active")) {
                nodeList[i].classList.remove("active");
                pointer[j].classList.remove("controlactive");
            }
            nodeList[count].classList.add("active");
            pointer[count].classList.add("controlactive")
        }
    }
    count += 1;
    if (count == nodeList.length) {
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

```css
.containimg .sliderimg {
    display: none;
}

.containimg .sliderimg.active.imageright {
    display: flex;
    animation: opac 0.8s;
}

.containimg .sliderimg.active.imageright2 {
    display: flex;
    animation: opac 0.8s;
}

.containimg .sliderimg.active.imageright3 {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.imageright {
    background-image: url('https://themewagon.github.io/jackson/images/img_bg_2.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.imageright2 {
    background-image: url('https://themewagon.github.io/jackson/images/img_bg_1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.controlnav {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 20px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.controlnav li {
    margin: 8px;
}


.controlpaging li a {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.controlpaging li a.controlactive {
    background: rgba(147, 147, 147, 0.795);
}
```

```html
<div class="containimg">
    <div class="imageright sliderimg active">
        <div class="textimage">
            <h1>I am</h1>
            <h2>a Designer</h2>
            <h3>100% html5 bootstrap templates Made</h3>
            <h3>by <a href="#" class="underline">colorlib.com</a></h3>
            <button class="viewportfolio mt-4">view portfolio <i
                    class="fa-solid fa-suitcase"></i></button>
        </div>
        <ol class="controlnav controlpaging">
            <li><a href="#" class="controlactive">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="imageright2 sliderimg">
        <div class="textimage">
            <h1>Hi!</h1>
            <h2>I'm Sarah</h2>
            <h3>100% html5 bootstrap templates Made</h3>
            <h3>by <a href="#" class="underline">colorlib.com</a></h3>
            <button class="viewportfolio mt-4">view portfolio <i
                    class="fa-solid fa-suitcase"></i></button>
        </div>
        <ol class="controlnav controlpaging">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="controlactive">2</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone kindly help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the problem is that you're getting two independent collections of Nodes, but using the same index to dereference them.

`.sliderimg` gets two `div` elements but `ol.controlnav li a` gets four `a` elements.  Your current code conflates these two independent collections.

If you are more specific about how you query your elements you will have more control and can use the same index:

```js
count = 0;

function displayImage() {
    // just get the active div (whichever one it is) and de-activate it
    let nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".sliderimg.active");
    for (let node of nodeList) {
        node.classList.remove("active");
        // just get the active `a` element that's a child of the active node
        let pointer = node.querySelector("ol.controlnav li a.controlactive")
        if (pointer) pointer.classList.remove("controlactive");
    }
    
    // just activate whichever div is next (and it's child a elem)
    nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".sliderimg");
    nodeList[count].classList.add("active");
    let pointerList = nodeList[count].querySelectorAll("ol.controlnav li a")
    pointerList[count].classList.add("controlactive")

    count += 1;
    if (count == nodeList.length) {
        count = 0;
    }
}

setInterval(displayImage, 4000)
```

```css
.containimg .sliderimg {
    display: none;
}

.containimg .sliderimg.active.imageright {
    display: flex;
    animation: opac 0.8s;
}

.containimg .sliderimg.active.imageright2 {
    display: flex;
    animation: opac 0.8s;
}

.containimg .sliderimg.active.imageright3 {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.imageright {
    background-image: url('https://themewagon.github.io/jackson/images/img_bg_2.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.imageright2 {
    background-image: url('https://themewagon.github.io/jackson/images/img_bg_1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.controlnav {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 20px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.controlnav li {
    margin: 8px;
}


.controlpaging li a {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.controlpaging li a.controlactive {
    background: rgba(147, 147, 147, 0.795);
}
```

```html
<div class="containimg">
    <div class="imageright sliderimg active">
        <div class="textimage">
            <h1>I am</h1>
            <h2>a Designer</h2>
            <h3>100% html5 bootstrap templates Made</h3>
            <h3>by <a href="#" class="underline">colorlib.com</a></h3>
            <button class="viewportfolio mt-4">view portfolio <i
                    class="fa-solid fa-suitcase"></i></button>
        </div>
        <ol class="controlnav controlpaging">
            <li><a href="#" class="controlactive">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="imageright2 sliderimg">
        <div class="textimage">
            <h1>Hi!</h1>
            <h2>I'm Sarah</h2>
            <h3>100% html5 bootstrap templates Made</h3>
            <h3>by <a href="#" class="underline">colorlib.com</a></h3>
            <button class="viewportfolio mt-4">view portfolio <i
                    class="fa-solid fa-suitcase"></i></button>
        </div>
        <ol class="controlnav controlpaging">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="controlactive">2</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it correct to put class="controlactive" in the second ol related to the second image?

Comment: Since I'm a newbie, would it be possible to have the code a little simpler? It works properly. But if it is possible I would like to have a simpler code

Comment: Not really, no.  It will be tolerated because there's no code that actually uses that class (but that may change - so, probably want to remove that)

Comment: Yes, but that's a different question.  Honestly (and this is a matter of opinion), the `controlnav` section should not be inside the `sliderimg` `div`, this would help reduce complexity.  You could actually do this with only a single `sliderimg` and replace the image link dynamically.  (i.e.  Have just a single `img` and iterate through an array of URLs for the `src`.  If you want to preload the images, put them in a hidden div.

Comment: could you please tell me how? I'm just learning to program, so I would like to have clearer ideas

Comment: also with a second solution, in order to understand the difference

Comment: There's actually a bunch of good references on how to build websites that would be a lot more effective for learning how to do it.  StackOverflow is literally for fixing bugs, and honestly  UX is not my primary interest.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131883/how-to-make-controls-of-a-customized-javascript-carousel